# Ransack - sorting on non-attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have two models, investor and opportunity.

Investor has_many opportunities and opportunity belongs_to investor

In the opportunity index view I've used ransack to set up sortable columns. It works for attributes of either model, however a using class method of Investor called "full_name" in a column isn't sortable.

Method in investor model

```
  def full_name
    return f_name + " " + l_name
  end
```

Index view for opportunity

```
<th><%= sort_link @search, :investor_full_name, "Investor" %></th>
```

It renders as a link and clicking the link shows the up/down arrow but does not sort.

Comment: You don't need `return` there. Just let the value "fall off" the end of the method.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that! It doesn't fix the issue however :-(

Comment: If you didn't solve this may be [this answer][1] will help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15434634/3828986